# is there a way to make the slider changes its value dynamically?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, slider

I have some data that I collect from my gps , after I calculate the distance between my current position and these gps data , I want the slider to move automatically when I approach to this point .

but the problem is , when I put a while loop to update the distance value , I get a bug in my UI . so I removed the loop but I can't display the new value of the distance in real time .

first , I calculated the distance between the first and the last point of my route , and I made this value as the Maximum value of my slider . 
the value of the slider that must change dynamically is the distance from the start point .

```cs
private async  void Prog()
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            double startpoint = distance_on_geoid(position.Latitude,position.Longitude,JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[0],JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[0]);
            double endpoint = distance_on_geoid(position.Latitude, position.Longitude, JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1().Count-1], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1().Count-1]);
            double alertDistance = distance_on_geoid(JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[0], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[0], JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1()[JSONData.GetGlcLatitude1().Count - 1], JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1()[JSONData.GetGlcLongitude1().Count - 1]);
            slider.Maximum = alertDistance;

            double startpoint_ = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", startpoint));
            test.Text = startpoint_.ToString();
                if (startpoint_>=0.01)
                {
                    slider.IsVisible = true;
                    slider.Value = alertDistance - endpoint;

            }
                else
                {
                    slider.IsVisible = false;
                }

        }
```

(JSONData ... is the values my route )

I expect the slider to move automatically when I approach to the end point . the slider must be visible only when im in the zone , otherwise it must be invisible.

Comment: Can I take a look on the while loop once?

Comment: @G.hakim it was something like this : while (true)
            {
                if (startpoint_ >= 0.01  )
                {
                    slider.IsVisible = true;
                    slider.Value = alertDistance - endpoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    slider.IsVisible = false;
                } }

Comment: Put your slider.value code inside the  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
               // write code to update UI
           });

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue now, it's happening because you are making a change on the UI from a background thread do something like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
{
 slider.IsVisible = true;
 slider.Value = alertDistance - endpoint;
}
```

Always see to it that you make changes on the UI on the MainThread and not some background thread i.e while using `async-await` for eg